# Zend Framework 2 - Doctrine 2, Translate annotated ObjectSelect strings

Tags: doctrine-orm, annotations, zend-framework2, translation

I have my doctrine 2 entity working just fine, but an entity field is an ObjectSelect (DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect), that have his **empty_option** parameter set to ***Security question***.

The problem is that I Can't get the string **Security question** into my module .po translation file, so I can't translate that string. If I manually add that string to the .po file, then, when I synchronize the .po file with PoEdit, it gets removed, because it is not contained inside a translate() method

Anyone knows how to get that string synchronized with PoEdit?

Thanks!

PS: This is the complete annotation for my $question field

```
/**
 * @var CsnUser\Entity\Question
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CsnUser\Entity\Question")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="question_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 * @Annotation\Type("DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect")
 * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StripTags"})
 * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StringTrim"})
 * @Annotation\Validator({"name":"Digits"})
 * @Annotation\Required(true)
 * @Annotation\Options({
 *   "required":"true",
 *   "empty_option": "Security question",
 *   "target_class":"CsnUser\Entity\Question",
 *   "property": "question"
 * })
 */
protected $question;
```

Comment: Welcome to the wonderfull world of limitations while using anotations. You could add a _('Security question') in your Entity and add it to the .po that way. But this is seriously a bad aproach imo. Why are you not using zf/forms instead?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the advise, I use annotations to be able to maintain only one codebase in my project. By the way, your proposed solution didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is rather nasty but works. Just add a translate with the string you want to translate into the construct of your Entity.

```
public function __construct()
{
....
   translate('Security question');
....
}
```

I'd usually still advice from using annotations, instead using [this](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/forms-and-actions.html) should give you all the control over your form's you'll need.

Comment: Hi, I can add _('Security question') to the entity constructor (not translate() because it doesn't exist in my entity), but the issue persists. I have the key translated now in my .po file thanks to the _() function but it doesn't gets translated.

Comment: Yes, this was correct, I was failing in this because I had messed up with tranlation domains! removed translation domains and everything got working